# Is it possible to create a 'variable' from two columns in a table and use that to look up result in another table

Tags: postgresql, node-postgres

I have a unique identifier "AB" in one table, "financials", that has values that looks like '123-456.' In Another table, "project_info" I have two columns "A" and "B" A has the first part of the dash and B has the second.

E.g. if financials has the "AB" of '123-456', project_info's "A" is 123 and "B" is 456.

My goal is to select information from the financials table where "AB" is equal to "A" from projects_info 'dash' "B" from projects_info.

An ideal SQL query in my head would look something like this:

`Select * from financials where "AB" = (select "A" from project_info)-(select "B" from project_info)`

I know that's no where near correct but I've tried doing something like this:

`select * from financials where "AB" = concat_ws((select "A" from projects_info), '-', (select "B" from projects_info))`

the error I get and expect is 
`more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

Is something like this possible in plain PostgreSQL code?

As an added piece of info, I want to ultimately call this query in Node using the package node-postgres.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) with that particular condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM financials f
JOIN projects_info pi ON(f."AB" = concat_ws('-', pi."A", pi."B")
```

Also you probably want to use `concat(pi."A", '-', pi."B")` or just `pi."A" || '-' || pi."B"` instead of `concat_ws`.

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly.